# select drop down option passed into a link ahref

Tags: php, html

How would I pass my  option to a URL parameter ?

select code:

```
echo "<select id=\"reasoncode\" name=\"reasoncode[$transnum]\"><option value=\"$ot_reasoncode\" default>$convert_rc</option><option value=\"0\"></option>"; select_reasoncode(); 
echo "</select>\n";
```

link with all pre-set paramters:

```
echo "<a href=\"file_action.php?id=$id&confirmsubmit=1&uid=$uid\" title=\"Submit\"><img src=\"images/submit.png\" border=\"0\"></a>
```

So basically all i want todo is somehow integrate that  drop down selection into my ahref link like so:

```
echo "<a href=\"file_action.php?id=$id&confirmsubmit=1&uid=$uid&SELECT=$SELECTVAR\" title=\"Submit\"><img src=\"images/submit.png\" border=\"0\"></a>
```

Is this possible??

Comment: It would be possible using javascript for example, but are you not simply looking for a submit button instead of a link?

Comment: no i want to use ahref (link) because i already have a <form> on the page

Comment: You can have multiple forms if you want to as long as you don't nest them.

Comment: well i just realized i can't do it with another <form> ... it would be <form> inside another <form>..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<select name="reasoncode" id="reasoncode" onchange="changePath();">
 <option value=""></option>
 <option value="page1.php?id=<?php echo $id;?>&confirmsubmit=1&uid=<?php echo $uid;?>">Option1</option>
 <option value="page2.php?id=<?php echo $id;?>&confirmsubmit=1&uid=<?php echo $uid;?>">Option2</option>
 <option value="page3.php?id=<?php echo $id;?>&confirmsubmit=1&uid=<?php echo $uid;?>">Option3</option>
</select>

<a id="link1" href="" target="_blank">CLICK</a>

<!--jquery min file-->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function changePath()
{
    var path= document.getElementById("reasoncode").value;
    alert(path);
    $("#link1").attr('href',path);
}
</script>
```

Comment: not really... when someone chooses something from drop down menu that option becomes a variable in my <a href="link.php?dropdown=$option">

Comment: the reason for this is because there will be more than one drop down menu with different options.. but i can't pass this thru a <form> only link <ahref>

Comment: it means when i select any option from select, anchor tag path value should be change with that selected option??

Comment: yeah probably javascript is the best way to go